# Why aren't there compatible JREs for JavaSE12+?

Tags: java

I am getting an error when trying to run a .java file as a Java Application and I get the following error:

`Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-14]' in project <project_name>`

I tried to change the execution environment and for JavaSE12 and later versions there are no compatible JREs. (But for JavaSE11 the compatible JRE is java-11-openjdk-amd64)

I do not know what to do because the project I am working on doesn't work with old Java versions. How can I choose an environment for the latest Java versions?

Note: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 if that makes any difference.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The JRE is just a subset of the JDK (i.e. the JDK is just the JRE with development tools included). Oracle does not offer a separate JRE-only download anymore. But other vendors do (e.g. Zulu Community, BellSoft Liberica, etc.). That being said, since you're developing an application you should want a JDK not only a JRE. Why do you specifically need a JRE only?

Comment: @Slaw I thought perhaps if I get a JRE that is compatible with my Java version that would solve the problem. The only thing I specifically need is for a JRE that is compatible with my version of Java or an alternative solution to the problem I described.

Comment: Well, as noted, other vendors offer JRE-only downloads. But the "alternative" is to just get the JDK.

Comment: @Slaw isn't openjdk11 supposed to work with Java 12+ however? (I am planning on using the latest version which is 15)

Comment: Depends what you mean by "work with". An application compiled with Java 11 will (should) run on Java 12+. But you can't use any features added in Java 12+ if all you have is JDK 11.

Comment: @Slaw Apologies. I meant would using jdk11 to work on a project that was build using a higher version of jdk work? Apparently Eclipse screams at you when you try to do that but I am not sure whether it is a Java thing or an Eclipse thing.

Comment: Code compiled with a newer version of Java (and that wasn't "cross-compiled") cannot be executed with an older version of Java. By the way, the current release of Java is version 15.0.2. Note that Java has recently moved to a six month major release cadence (with at least two minor releases/patches in between). I believe Java 16 should be released some time in March of this year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

I am not a Linux user, so I may not know best. But I suspect the simplest approach to running your .java file is to:

- Obtain and install a JDK for Java 15 for Linux
- Call `java` app on the command-line, passing the path to your .java file.

Backwards-compatibility is a priority for the Java team. Most any existing Java app should be able to run with the latest version of Java. There are exceptions, but they are *very* few.

## JRE is passé

The JRE (*Java Runtime Environment*) was a subset of the [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) (*Java Development Kit*), omitting some of the programmer tools. The JRE as a separate product seems to be getting phased out.

Oracle and much of the Java community has shifted away from the idea of regular users having Java installed on their personal computers. Instead, apps should be delivered with a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) specific to their host platform bundled within the app. This bundling of a JVM can be done using newer tools such as [jlink](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282) and [jpackage](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/392).

For more info, read:

- [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf) - Oracle (2020-05)
- [*Java is still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244)

## Obtain a JDK

You said you have a .java file to execute. That file must first be compiled before it can be executed. The more recent versions of the `java` app can do both steps at the same time, compile & execute.

First download and install a JVM for your host platform.

[Java 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11) is the current [long-term support (LTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version. [Java 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_15) is the latest release. You may want to read about the six-month [release cadence for Java](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/update-and-faq-on-the-java-se-release-cadence).

You have a bounty of vendor choices providing implementations of Java. Here is a graphic flowchart I made to assist in choosing a vendor.

If the steps shown here are overwhelming, I suggest either:

- Using `apt-get` or similar package installer to obtain a build of OpenJDK for Ubuntu. I am not a Linux-user, so I do not know the details.
- Head over to [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net) to download an installer for Linux.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

Some motivations to consider in selecting a vendor.

[image: Motivations in choosing a vendor for Java]

## Compile & run your app

Once your JDK is installed, on a console (such as Terminal.app in macOS), run something like the following. The `java` command should both compile and execute your `.java` file, if that single file makes up your entire app.

```sh
java /path/to/some/folder/MyJavaApp.java
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting the same info all the time. Yes, it's a very nice flowchart. No, it does not to be on every question about the JDK. It would be better to make one canonical and start closing these kind of things as dupes.

Comment: @Michael FYI, I have indeed closed *many* duplicates on Stack Overflow. Thanks so much for your valuable input. Strange though, I am not seeing the duplicate that you linked for this Question when you voted to close.

Comment: I didn't vote to close. What am I'm saying is that you have posted this flowchart at least 3 times, and that's just ones that I've stumbled upon. I suspect it's more. If you find yourself routinely posting the same information, that should be a clue to an established user like you that there are already suitable dupe candidates. If you don't think that, perhaps the most efficient use of your time would be to create a canonical that can be used as such.

Comment: @BasilBourque Very thorough explanation, thanks. (Although not all of it was necessary to solve my issue, it is still appreciated and will probably be useful to future visitors of this question). I ended up installing jdk-15 (I couldn't use apt to do it so i did it manually) and then I changed the (default) version used by the OS. Finally I had to let Eclipse know where the directory to the installation is. To conclude with, the key step is to install jdk 15 which i didn't know existed (yes, I am a newbie).